# Impute value cell with condition

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame( Date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-25"),
                   idx = c(1, 2, 3,  4,5, 6, 3),
                   Temp = c(2, 5, 12, 12,12, 1, 5),
                   idy=   c(1, 3,  1, 6,  2, 5, 9))
```

where idx and idy are references and Temp are temperatures.

What I would like to do is replace values in Temp>10 doing the following.

In this case for Temp = 12, idy are 1,6,2 and if you compare that idy with idx 
take the mean of the temperatures of that idx. . Sorry but it´s hard to explain. Here is what I want:

```
df <- data.frame( Date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-25"),
                   idx = c(1, 2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 3),
                   Temp = c(2, 5, 2.66, 2.66, 2.66, 1, 5),
                   idy=   c(1, 3,  1, 6,  2, 5, 9))
```

where 2.66 = (2+5+1)/3 which are the temperatures of the idx=idy of the temperature over 10.

I have tried with this:

```
df = df %>%  group_by(Date) %>% mutate( Temp = ifelse ( Temp >10 , mean(Temp[idy =idx] , na.rm = TRUE), Temp))
```

But the mean is not calculated in a proper way. The value is 7.33 instead of 2.66.

Comment: sorry for the error but still does not work,

Comment: Still not clear why 2+5+1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly and if there are no more edge cases this should work

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Temp = replace(Temp, Temp > 10, mean(Temp[idx %in% idy[Temp > 10]])))


#        Date idx     Temp idy
#1 2017-02-23   1 2.000000   1
#2 2017-02-23   2 5.000000   3
#3 2017-02-23   3 2.666667   1
#4 2017-02-23   4 2.666667   6
#5 2017-02-23   5 2.666667   2
#6 2017-02-23   6 1.000000   5
#7 2017-02-25   3 5.000000   9
```

Also we can do this directly,

```
with(df, replace(Temp, Temp > 10, mean(Temp[idx %in% idy[Temp > 10]])))
#[1] 2.000000 5.000000 2.666667 2.666667 2.666667 1.000000 5.000000
```

Logic is to `replace` all the `Temp` values greater than 10 by first finding their corresponding `idy` values, then `idx` and get the `mean` of those `Temp` values.

Comment: That really works but it needs a group_by(date) before mutate isn´t it?.                    
  df %>% group_by (Date) %>%
  mutate(Temp = replace(Temp, Temp > 10, mean(Temp[idx %in% idy[Temp > 10]])))

Comment: @s157 ohh..ok. I didn't knew you were grouping by `Date`. Yes you can add `group_by(Date)` if you want that.